# Action / GET with limited properties

Tags: api-platform.com

Certainly already asked but...
Having this entity

```php
/**
 * A form
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=FormRepository::class)
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="forms",
 *     options={"comment":"Table of the forms"},
 *     indexes={
 *         @ORM\Index(name="forms_idx_dofc", columns={"dateofcreation"}),
 *         @ORM\Index(name="forms_idx_dofu", columns={"dateofupdate"}),
 *         @ORM\Index(name="forms_idx_dofs", columns={"dateofsubmission"})
 *     }
 * )
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     routePrefix="/",
 *     shortName="Forms",
 *     description="API Access : form Entity",
 *     collectionOperations={"GET"},
 *     itemOperations={"GET"},
 *     attributes={
 *         "normalization_context"={
 *             "groups"={
 *                 "GET:FORM"
 *             }
 *         },
 *         "order"={
 *             "dateofsubmission",
 *             "dateofupdate",
 *             "dateofcreation"
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
 *
 */
class Form
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"comment":"Primary Key, Auto generated"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var datetime Date of creation of the form.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"comment":"date of creation of the form"})
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The date time when was created the form should not be blank")
     * @Assert\DateTime(message="The data time when was created the form should be the type DateTime")
     *
     * @Groups({"GET:FORM"})
     *
     * @ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, strategy="ASC")
     */
    private $dateofcreation;

    /**
     * @var datetime Date of update of the form.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", options={"comment":"date of update of the form"})
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The date time when was updated the form should not be blank")
     * @Assert\DateTime(message="The data time when was updated the form should be the type DateTime")
     *
     * @Groups({"GET:FORM"})
     *
     * @ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, strategy="ASC")
     */
    private $dateofupdate;
   /**
     * @var person Person that has created the form.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Person::class, inversedBy="forms")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     * @Groups({"GET:FORM"})
     *
     * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"createdBy.id":"exact","createdBy.givenname":"ipartial", "createdBy.familyname":"ipartial"})
     * @ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, strategy="ASC")
     */
    private $createdBy;

...
```

I would like to have the possibility of having :
A base collectionOperations "GET" would return all the properties that have the @GROUP=GET:FORM

A alternate collectionOperations "GETDATES" would return all properties that have a @GROUP=GET:DATES

The operations being accessible (ideally) with different routes.

GET => # http://api/forms?createdBy.id=25 => All properties

GETDATES => http://api/formsLimited?createdBy.id=25 => only the dates

ps: I hope this is better for the readability.

Comment: Your post is unreadable. You can indeed use [serialization groups](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/issues) to return a limited set of properties for a given operation, and you can also use [property filter](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/issues) to let the client choose them.

Comment: Sorry for the "quality" of the post, I was in the rush. I will check the serialisation groups and property filter;

Comment: Edit your own post, add code quotes, past the valuable part of your entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Grégoire Hébert(https://stackoverflow.com/users/4887997/gr%C3%A9goire-hebert) for the support (on Slack).
The solution is quite simple.
Create in the ApiResource() a collection operation with:

- Method = GET
- path (that will become a route)
- the normalization context for the group to be applied to the wanted properties

It gives:

```
collectionOperations={"GET","GETLIMITED"={"method"="GET","path"="formslist","normalization_context"={"groups"="GET:LIMITED"}}},
```